# Cyclically pop the contents of one list into a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, cycle, nested-lists

I have a list

```
main_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

and I want to split the lists into multiple lists and I want the output as shown below-

```
list1 = [1,9]    
list2 = [2,10]    
list3 = [3,11]    
list4 = [4,12]    
list5 = [5]    
list6 = [6]    
list7 = [7]
list8 = [8]
```

Comment: What is the condition based on which you want to split the original list?

Comment: @Jack Describe your logic of splitting

Comment: pop the 1st element of the list and append it in list 1, pop the 2nd element of the list and append it in list 2 and so on. Each element should be appended in the consecutive list

Comment: @Jack You accepted the worst solution of the 3. What a shame.

Comment: OK, it is not a fancy solution, others can be nicer. But it is simple, easy to understand and doesn't use extra libraries.

Comment: @Jack Please refrain from mutilating your question. I've reversed your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple code:

```
main_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

list_count = 8
lists = [[] for _ in range(list_count)]

for count, item in enumerate(main_list):
    lists[count % list_count].append(item)

print(lists)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 11], [4, 12], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

**EDIT**

If

```
main_list = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2)]
```

then output

```
[[(1, 1), (3, 1)], [(1, 2), (3, 2)], [(1, 3)], [(1, 4)], [(2, 1)], [(2, 2)], [(2, 3)], [(2, 4)]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved in a matter of lines using `itertools.cycle`.

```
from itertools import cycle

main_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
lists = [[] for _ in range(8)]

for x, y in zip(cycle(lists), main_list):
     x.append(y)
```

Complexity: `O(n)`.

---

```
print(lists)
[[1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 11], [4, 12], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

Comment: It's a nice solution indeed. `groupby` is also kinda elegant, albeit with `O(n.log n)` complexity.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, did you notice a decrease in upvotes for python questions? I've written many answers in the last few days, which AFAICT, are correct. Often, there's no comment, no vote. It seems to be the same for the other answerers.

Comment: @EricDuminil If you're talking about the last few days, it's because weekends are usually downtime. If you're talking about in general, I would imagine it's the [gamesmanship mentality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323414/incentivizing-people-to-avoid-gamesmanship). I love getting recognition and upvotes as much as the next guy, but more than that I believe in sportsmanship. So, if a fellow answerer made it known to me that they had upvoted, I would almost always return the favour. I would much rather both our answers were stuck at +1, than both stuck at 0.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to group the integers by `modulo 8`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def f(x):
    return (x-1) % 8

main_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

main_list.sort(key=f)
print(main_list)
# [1, 9, 2, 10, 3, 11, 4, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8]

print([list(l) for _,l in groupby(main_list, key=f)])
# [[1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 11], [4, 12], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library that implements a tool for this:

```
> pip install more_itertools
```

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

[list(c) for c in mit.distribute(8, iterable)]
# [[1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 11], [4, 12], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

Elements of an iterable are distributed among the `n` chunks.  See [`more_itertools` docs](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distribute) for details.

---

Another simple approach, unique to this problem:

```
import itertools as it


lst, n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 8

[list(filter(None, i)) for i in it.zip_longest(lst[:n], lst[n:])]
# [[1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 11], [4, 12], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

Two sliced lists are fully zipped while filtering `None` from each sub-element.